# limit equals the imaginary number, i

Tags: limits

Hello can a limit equal just the imaginary number? and if it does equal the imaginary number, i does the limit exist? I computed a limit of a function which contained z(complex number) and I used L'Hopital's rule and I got the limit, i. So I was wondering whether that meant that the limit exists or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a limit can be equal to an imaginary number.

For example, the constant sequence $\{a_j\}_{j=1}^\infty$ where $a_j=i$ converges to $i$.

If you are working with complex number, a sequence can converge to a complex number.

Comment: so the limit can be equal to the imaginary number only if the function is complex valued right? this wont work with a function that i real-valued ?

Comment: For the limit to be equal to $i$, it has to get arbitrary close to $i$. If a function is real, there is a minimal distance of $1$ away from $i$.